# Want to Activate previous workbook in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 active workbook and adding another multiple workbooks basis on column data
and same saving with Basis on Next function and giving value of column
Need to activate new added workbook but problem is every time workbook name is different basis on column hence unable to activate the same basis on name
Help to activate another workbook

Activate the another workbook (previous workbook) without declaring name

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding new workbooks, they're normally activated, then you can use `ActiveWorkbook.Name`, if you're however opening workbooks depending on a cell's value, you can use that when setting it to a Workbook object.
In this example, the paths to workbooks are in the A-column:

```
Sub openWorkbooksFromVariables()
    Dim Lastrow As Long, i As Long
    Dim wbQ As Workbook, wbB As Workbook
    Dim qPath As String
    
    Lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set wbB = ActiveWorkbook 'current workbook is now accessible through wbB
    For i = 2 To Lastrow
        qPath = "" & Range("A" & i).Value & ""
        Set wbQ = Workbooks.Open(qPath)
        wbQ.Activate
        wbQ.Save
        wbQ.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

If there's anything more needed, please update your question with an example.